# Setting scroll position of JScrollPane after repaint of content Pane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a `JScrollPane` with a `JPanel` in it, which shows something like a time sheet. This time sheet panel is zoomable abd scrollable. I have many entries in this time sheet panel, each entry is an own panel and has a start time and a length.

When I now click on an entry in this time sheet, I want to zoom in this entry and, of course, move to it.

For example: The actual zoom shows 3 Month from January to March. Now I have an entry at the 1st of March until the 3rd of March. This entry is now for example 10 pixel long. Wren I click on this entry, the zoom factor is changed in that way, that the time sheet only shows 3 days and starts on the 1st of March, so that the entries width is over the complete scroll panes view port.

For this, I calculate the new zoom factor and the new Start X Position of the time sheet panel and call a repaint of the panel.

This works with the zoom, but because the time sheet panel has not the new width at this moment, this leads to that the scroll pane scrollbars have not the new sizes. So I can not set the new scrollbar position at this point of code.

So, how can I set the right scrollbar position **after** the repaint of the scroll pane is done and the scrollers have their new sizes?

Here is some pseudo code for mor understanding (Sorry for the formating but I didnt manage to paste the code so that the indents are correct):

```
public class MyRootPanel extends JPanel
{
TimeSheetPanel tsPanel = new TimeSheetPanel(this);
tsPanel.setLayout(null);

scrollPanel=new JScrollPane(tsPanel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
this.add(scrollPanel);

public setScrollPos(int xPos)
{
    scrollPanel.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(xPos);
}
}

public class TimeSheetPanel extends JPanel
{
MyRootPanel rootPanel;

public int pixelPerHour = 5; // Zoom factor
public int rowHeight = 30; // height of one row on table

public TimeSheetPanel(MyRootPanel root)
{
    rootPanel = root;

    this.setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0,0, maxDays * pixelPerHour *24, maxrows * rowHeight);

    for(Entry e : entryList)
    {
        EntryPanel entryPanel = new EntryPanel(this, entry);
        this.add(entryPanel);
    }
}

public void zoomToEntry(Entry entry)
{
    // calc new zoom factor here.
    pixelPerHour = ......
    newXPos = .....
    // and set it to the panel
    setBounds(0,0, maxDays * pixelPerHour *24, maxrows * rowHeight);
    // call repaint
    repaint();
    // THIS WILL NOT WORK
    rootPanel.setScrollPos(newXPos);
}

}

public class EntryPanel extends JPanel
{
TimeSheetPanel parentPanel;
Entry entry;

public EntryPanel(TimeSheetPanel parent, Entry e)
{
    parentPanel = parent;
    Entry = e;

    this.setLayout(null);

    int left = entry.start * parentPanel.pixelPreHour;
    int width = entry.length * parentPanel.pixelPerHour;
    int top = entry.row * parentPanel.rowHeight;
    int height = parentPanel.rowHeight;

    setBounds(left, top, width, height);

    addMouseListener(this);

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2)  
    {
        parentPanel.zoomToEntry(entry);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `myJScrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(myZoomedJPanel.getBounds);`, or you can to centering (to the `JViewport`) by using, calculating inserect from two `Rectangle`s (one from `JViewport` and second from `JPanel`), e.g. `myJScrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, (int) rect2.getWidth(), (int) rect2.getHeight()));`

Comment: Thanks for that, but that is not solving my problem, that I dont know WHERE to place this code. My repaint() is called form the entry panel in the timesheet panel, which itself is inside the scrollpane. So when i call repaint() in this entry panel and direktly after the repaint() one of yours methods, it will not work, because the scrollpane dos not have its new sizes now. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: *"..I dont know WHERE to place this code."* In your code at line 357. (That was sarcasm, BTW). For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

For anybody searching for an answer, I solved my problem by using invokeLater

```
    repaint();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            valuePanelScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(xpos);
            valuePanelScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(ypos);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't know why and how it works. But it did for me. Suprisingly(?) when i was just using
`valuePanelScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(xpos);` it wasn't working. If anyone knows why and could clarify i would be gratefull. Thanks for the answer anyway.